# Ensure maintainability & testability in file-processing application

Tags: vb.net

### Problem

I want to refactor an old application which has grown over time and is awful to maintain/test. Basically the app needs to read an file an process it lines.

The file to be read can be compared to a CSV-file, where the first field determines the type of the line, something like this:

```
1,abcd,... 
1,3423,... 
2,"abc",... 
5,test,...
```

Currently the application works like this (pseudo-code):

```
For Each line in file.getLines()
  if (line.StartsWith("1,") then
    ' Process line of type 1
  elseif (line.StartsWith("2,") then
    ' Process line of type 2
  ...
  End If
Next
```

This obviously is a nightmare to maintain and test. Therefore I'd like refactor this whole thing and thought of doing it like this:

- Create a parser for each line-type
- Let each parser register itself to a handler, which will raise an event for each line

### Code Idea

Handler:

```
Public Class ParserHandler

  Public Event Parse(RepLine As ReportLine)
  Public Event FileFinished()

  Public Sub RaiseParse(RepLine As ReportLine)
      RaiseEvent Parse(RepLine)
  End Sub

  Public Sub RaiseFileFinished()
      RaiseEvent FileFinished()
  End Sub

End Class
```

Parser:

```
Public Class FirstParser

  Public Sub New(Handler As ParserHandler)
      AddHandler Handler.Parse, AddressOf Parse
      AddHandler Handler.FileFinished, AddressOf FileFinished
  End Sub

  Public Sub Parse(RepLine As ReportLine)
      If Not RepLine.Type = 1 Then
          Return
      End If

      ' Process
    End Sub

  Private Sub FileFinished()
    ' Final stuff, eg. insert into DB
  End Sub

End Class
```

Main:

```
Dim ParserHandler As New ParserHandler()
Dim FirstParser As New FirstParser(ParserHandler)
Dim SecondParser As New SecondParser(ParserHandler)
...

For Each line in file.getLines()
  ' Extract Id and construct ReportLine-object here
  ParserHandler.RaiseParse(ReportLine)
Next
```

I think this looks way better than the original version, but I'm still not convinced that this is really the way to go. In case of testing the parsers with unit tests, I still have to create a handler first. This might be ok, but *feels* wrong as the parser should be testable separately (is it wrong?).

I like the use of events in this case, as not every parser needs to implement every possible event of the handler, which prevents me from just having an IParser interface.

What do you think of this approach, is it good to go? Are there any best practices/design pattern I should look into for a clean solution to this problem?

Comment: What I would personally do in this situation is calling every time a function in charge of getting all the values (e.g., via simple `Split`); the first value would be analysed to determine the actions to perform. If the actions are simple enough, I would rely on a set of if else statements; if they are a bit too complex, I might create different functions (to be called manually or even via delegate); I would try to group different actions together (i.e., no one action per function). In any case, I think that over-thinking how to improve certain code is not too positive...

Comment: ...mainly when dealing with hardcoded lists; because you will always have to keep the ugly hardcoded part. What might be more useful here is making the system dynamically definable (i.e., able to account for new cases via external resource, like a file). For example: a config file where each line represent a possible scenario: 1|4|action_whatever|... the first number is the id; the second one the number of letters in the second field, the third one an action understood by the given parser, etc. This seems more important than changing the actual algorithm and keeping the hardcoded enumerations.

Comment: @varocarbas opinion-based questions are _very_ poor fit for Programmers, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat SE Programmers too! (Code Review has similar problems)! Nobody wants what is offtopic in SO? They should create a new SE site, OffTopic. I am joking. Thanks for the info, I will bear this in mind for the future.